# How to add category "Figures" before "A" in index?

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, xindy

I'd like to create a category (letter group) named "Figures" before the first letter
"A" in the index. The following correctly puts "Figure description, 1" in
its own category (not under "F"), but the category header "Figures" doesn't appear:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[noautomatic]{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\newcommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
  \par{\sffamily\bfseries #1}\par
  \nopagebreak
}

% Doesn't seem to change anything:
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.xdy}
(define-letter-group "Figures" :before "A" :prefixes ("+"))
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
The index\index{index} should contain a category (letter group) called
``Figures''\index{figures} and that should contain the entry ``Figure
description, 1'' \index{+@Figure description}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

I haven't used `xindy` before, so not sure if that requires something differently.
I compile with `texi2pdf` as usual (and this seems to call `xindy`) and I hope it can remain this way.

I searched quite a bit but couldn't find much related. It must be trivial to add an additional category before "A" (or so I thought).

**Update**

Here is a hack based on `imakeidx` alone. It's pretty ugly, though, as one would manually need to add a number in front of all symbols and a symbol in front of all figures. If one could at least tell `makeindex` to print symbols *after* numbers, then it would suffice to start `\index{}` commands for figures with numbers (I'd like to see the figures before the symbols). But even then only one additional category (figures) could be handled, not more (say you want to see figures and lists, then symbols, then A to Z; this case can't be handled by this hack).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options=-s myindexstyle.ist]

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{myindexstyle.ist}
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\sffamily\\bfseries "
heading_suffix "\\hfill}\\nopagebreak\n\\nopagebreak"
numhead_positive "Miscellaneous"
numhead_negative "misc"
symhead_positive "Figures"
symhead_negative "figs"
delim_0 ",\~"
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
The index\index{*@Figure 2 description} should contain\index{contain} a category (letter group) called
``Figures''\index{figures} and that should contain\index{0@$e$} the entry ``Figure
description, 1'' \index{*@Figure 1 description}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: It might be easier to create two separate indexes.  There are many packages and example of multiple indexes here.  Also, do you really want your figures in alphabetical order, or would a List of Figures do?

Comment: Thanks, John. Indeed, two indices with `imakeidx` and two style files would get close. But I think they will be vertically separated. The figures could be forced to only fill the left column in the first index that is printed, but the right column would still remain empty before the index with A-Z begins. Or you fill both columns with the figures, but then you need a separate heading for the A-Z index and that looks strange.

Comment: There are ways to reduce or eliminate the extra space, like `\let\imki@clearpage=\relax`.  It depends on the implementation.